# SvelteKit/Vite/Tailwindcss/Supabase Project: MIME Type Error when Loading Module Script

Tags: javascript

I'm new on sveltkit and have been working on a project using SvelteKit with Vite as my bundler. I've encountered an issue that I can't seem to resolve. Whenever I try to run my application on my machine, I get the following error on the browser, (nothing on server side):

```
failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.


Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:5173/@fs/Users/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXX/.svelte-kit/generated/client/app.js
```

The content displays correctly, but due to the error, the JavaScript isn't functioning as indicted by the error.

For context, here are my devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.28.1",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^2.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.20.4",
    "@types/nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.45.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.45.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "daisyui": "^3.5.1",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.30.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.28",
    "prettier": "^2.8.0",
    "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.10.1",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "svelte": "^4.0.5",
    "svelte-check": "^3.4.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.0",
    "vite": "^4.4.2",
    "vitest": "^0.32.2"
  },
```

on server side no error (no information) :

```
npm run dev 

> vite dev



  VITE v4.4.9  ready in 1485 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue or can provide any guidance on how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!